# How to resolve Hibernate configuration object error

Tags: hibernate

Can some please help me to resolve this issue. i am geting an error while involking the configure method using Configuration object refrence[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aMV5.png)

i have code the xml file like below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HynAW.png)